# Efficient random sampling of constrained n-dimensional space

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, genetic-algorithm

I'm about to optimize a problem that is defined by n (n>=1, typically n=4) non-negative variables. This is not a n-dimensional problem since the sum of all the variables needs to be 1.

The most straightforward approach would be for each x_i to scan the entire range 0<=x_i<1, and then normalizing all the values to the sum of all the x's. However, this approach introduces redundancy, which is a problem for many optimization algorithms that rely on stochastic sampling of the solution space (genetic algorithm, taboo search and others). Is there any alternative algorithm that can perform this task?

**What do I mean by redundancy?**

Take two dimensional case as an example. Without the constrains, this would be a two-dimensional problem which would require optimizing two variables. However, due to the requirement that X1 + X2 == 0, one only needs to optimize one variable, since X2 is determined by X1 and vice versa. Had one decided to scan X1 and X2 independently and normalizing them to the sum of 1, then many solution candidates would have been identical vis-a-vis the problem. For example (X1==0.1, X2==0.1) is identical to (X1==0.5, X2==0.5).

Comment: Out of curiosity: what kind of 'redundancy' are you talking about? I'm not really familiar with the field.

Comment: You may also have more luck on one of specialized SE sites (there's a whole separate site about statistics, IIRC)

Comment: Lots of interesting words that are mostly unnecessary but what's entirely missing is the objective of the algorithm. The title "Efficient random sampling of constrained n-dimensional space" indicates an n-dimensional problem that's then refuted in the first paragraph. I'm not sure how the sum of the values relates to the dimensionality of the problem space, perhaps you could explain.

Comment: @Lazarus: the constraint (sum == 1) reduces the space to an (n-1) dimensional subspace. But I must admit, I also don't see the 'redundancy'.

Comment: I take it that you're looking for uniform sampling over the n-1 - dimensional space.

Comment: Please specify a little more about your criteria for independent candidates and why you normalize a candidate set before you act on it. Also, what do you want to do with redundant candidate sets? For example, can you tell us what you'd ideally want in a data set that had (x1 = .1, x2 = .1) and (x1 = .5, x2 = .5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with real valued variables then arriving with 2 samples that become identical is quite unlikely. However you do have the problem that your samples would not be uniform. You are much more likely to choose (0.5, 0.5) than (1.0, 0). Oneway of fixing this is subsampling. Basically what you do is that when you are shrinking space along a certain point, you shrink the probability of choosing it.

So basically what you are doing is mapping all the points that are inside the unit cube that satisfy that are in the same direction, map to a single points. These points in the same direction form a line. The longer the line, the larger the probability that you will choose the projected point. Hence you want to bias the probability of choosing a point by the inverse of the length of that line.

Here is the code that can do it(Assuming you are looking for x_is to sum up to 1):

```
while(true) {
      maximum = 0;
      norm = 0;
      sum = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         x[i] = random(0,1);
         maximum = max(x[i], max);
         sum += x[i];
         norm += x[i] * x[i];
      }
      norm = sqrt(norm);
      length_of_line = norm/maximum;
      sample_probability = 1/length_of_line;

      if (sum == 0 || random(0,1) > sample_probability) {
        continue;
      } else {
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         x[i] = x[i] /sum;
      } 
      return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same function [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986886/efficient-random-sampling-of-constrained-n-dimensional-space/3990339#3990339) earlier by [Amit Prakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480855/amit-prakash), translated to python

```
import numpy as np

def f(N):
    while(True):
        count += 1
        x = np.random.rand(N)
        mxm = np.max(x)
        theSum = np.sum(x)
        nrm = np.sqrt(np.sum(x * x))
        length_of_line = nrm / mxm
        sample_probability = 1 / length_of_line
        if theSum == 0 or rand() > sample_probability:
            continue
        else:
            x = x / theSum
        return x
```